# special character in folder string here @

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

I have been searching intensively, but the returning results are not quite what I am trying to achieve.
I want to access a remote folder on a server. The pain point comes (I assume) from the @ in the name of the folder name. And that @ with regards to folder name of course leads to the '\\' topic in all results I googled, which are not my issue, even though it probably is an 'illegal' character topic. 

For Debugging I copy the content of the string rootFolderPath and pasted it into a browser / explorer it opens up, as it should (using in both cases the same windows UID).
The first example (in the comments) for rootFolderPath runs nicely without problems. The problem shows up in the `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles` line

The third example results in the same error, which is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: The network path was not found.

What can I do to access that folder? I cannot change the name of the folder (as out of reach) unfortunately.

```
    //string rootFolderPath = "D:\\Data\\temp\\Debug\\";
    string rootFolderPath ="\\\\shareroom1.eu.test.de@SSL\\DavWWWRoot\\de\\itgqc\\Operational Slide Decks\\Public\\Server with Open Shares (Config Mgmnt)";
    // string rootFolderPath = @"\\shareroom1.eu.test.de@SSL\DavWWWRoot\de\itgqc\Operational Slide Decks\Public\Server with Open Shares (Config Mgmnt)";

    string filesToDelete = @"list_" + tower + "*.xlsx";   // Only delete XLSX files containing "list_" in their filenames

    string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath, filesToDelete); <---- here I get the error
     foreach (string file in fileList)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(file + " will be deleted");
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (file + " will be deleted");
       try
       {
        System.IO.File.Delete(file);
       }
        catch (IOException) 
        { log.Error("Could not delete " + file + " probably was blocked");}
      }
```

Environment: VS 2015 and .NET 4.6.1

Comment: I think the problem is more that the @ is not in the folder name, but the machine name portion of that unc

Comment: `@` *inside* a string literal or variable has zero side effects - what is `@SSL`  ? If its a directory your missing a preceding \

Comment: have you tried using the IP address of the machine instead?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc952

Comment: What is that ` in your third example?

Comment: I think that problem is not related to `@` char in folder path, it my be something else.

Comment: It may be your application does not have access rights to the folder rather than be an issue with the @ character. Can you map a drive to the folder with "NET USE" & access it that way.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the path is actually a WebDAV server instead of a Windows SMB.

Comment: the ' in my third example is an obvious typo which came in formating the question (btw. English is not my primary language).

Comment: The net use idea is smart, as it does (surprisingly) not work, while a copy and paste to the Explorer URL did. So I am going to look into WebDav as Alejandro was suggesting. Thx for the push into that direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would use StringBuilder - and make the at sign a CHAR variable with the ASCII equivalent (don't have my green card handy right now)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("\\\\shareroom1.eu.test.de")
sb.Append('@'); // replace with ASCII here if necessary
sb.Append("SSL\DavWWWRoot\de\itgqc\Operational Slide Decks\Public\Server with Open Shares (Config Mgmnt)");
rootFolderPath = sb.ToString();
```